# Dropdown goes off on selecting any field in date picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I have a drop down in which the user can register. I have a date of birth field which has a date picker. When I select anything in datepicker the dropdown disappears.

JS:

```
 $( " #datepicker " ).datepicker ({ 
    maxDate: 0,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true, 
    dateFormat : 'dd-mm-yy',
    yearRange: '1955:2030'
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row form-group" >
<h6 class="lable">Date Of Birth</h6>
<input type="text" id="datepicker" placeholder="Date of Birth" name="dateofbirth"  class="form-control text-field" required/>
</div>
```

Comment: Unless I misunderstand your problem, that **is** the way they work--the dropdown appears, and hides as soon as you select something.

Comment: Please give me a solution hw can i fix issue @Ted

Comment: Could you be clearer on exactly what your issue is? What you have described is how the `datepicker` is meant to work.

Comment: @KishoreJv - answer added below.

Comment: i have a dropdown in a page where user will be allowed to register.. i have a date of birth field for which ia m trying to use date picker.. calender pops but  when i select year or month the drop down disappears and only calender remains .. thats the issue @JoeyCiechanowicz

Answer (score 2):

Add the below `onSelect` and `onClose` functions to have it remain open (run the snippet to see it work):

```js
 $("#datepicker").datepicker({
   maxDate: 0,
   changeMonth: true,
   changeYear: true,
   dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
   yearRange: '1955:2030',
   onSelect: function () {
        $(this).data('datepicker').inline = true;
   },
   onClose: function () {
        $(this).data('datepicker').inline = false;
   }
 });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="row form-group">
  <h6 class="lable">Date Of Birth</h6>
  <input type="text" id="datepicker" placeholder="Date of Birth" name="dateofbirth" class="form-control text-field" required/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, thats how the datepicker is meant to work. You click on an input element and it shows the datepicker, and then when you select a date it dissapears and puts the value selected in the input element.

You need to make sure that you are loading `jQuery`, `jQuery UI` and any theme you are using.

```js
 $("#datepicker").datepicker({
   maxDate: 0,
   changeMonth: true,
   changeYear: true,
   dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
   yearRange: '1955:2030'
 });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="row form-group">
  <h6 class="lable">Date Of Birth</h6>
  <input type="text" id="datepicker" placeholder="Date of Birth" name="dateofbirth" class="form-control text-field" required/>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried including them still cant fix my problem.. :(

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>


</body>
</html>
```

### **https://jsfiddle.net/pgujyp1k/**